# UFD 0.5 not rendered in IE 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery with  [UFD Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/ufd/) for select drop down. It  works cool  , I facing is IE 7 , It not rendered.

My code.

```
 <div id="first">
            <select id="eventEg" name="eventEg">
               <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>

          </select>
   </div>
<div id="second">
           <select id="eventEg" name="eventEg">
               <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>

          </select>
</div>



          var master = $("div#first #eventEg").ufd();
           var another=$("div#second  #eventEg").ufd();
```

I am using jQuery 1.5.1,in  firefox it works fine.

In IE , The first drop down Renders where as the second dropdown not
rendered.

Let me know how to fix the problem in iE7 (I think it is because of select id unique, How ever i  need with out changing the select id as unique, Since I inserted the select  ID into div )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs [**MUST**](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) be unique, you **CANNOT** use the same ID twice! As you see it breaks things. If you want to use the same *thing* for more than one element, use `class` instead of `id`.